# Make DIV appear immediately without fadein effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the JavaScript setinterval method, but the DIV appears slowly. Could someone please tell me how to remove the fadein effect? I need for it to appear immediately.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
 setInterval(
function()
{
$('#lista').show().load('pagination.php').fadeIn('slow');}, 0);
</script>
```

Comment: Is your delete key not working?

Comment: Could you please post a self contained snippet with valid syntax instead of an arbitrary fragment of your code?

Comment: You've now removed the `fadeIn` effect yourself! The question is now really confusing.

Comment: Ive restored the `fadeIn('slow')` that was there when you oginally asked the question. Without it the question and answers given make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow that is a simple question, and one that you could have learned quickly by reading a bit of [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/). But no matter.

```
$('#lista').show().load('pagination.php');
```

You see, you're already showing the element with id `lista` and then loading some html into it. No need to have the `fadeIn` on the end.

A possibly better way to achieve the same thing, however only showing the element once the data is loaded, is to pass a callback to the `load` method:

```
$('#lista').load('pagination.php', function(){ $(this).show();} );
```

Comment: This script allows me to reload the page after a few seconds, if i put like you say it shows me errors..

Comment: @ossial - I dont see any code in your question which would reload a page. As as been commented above please post some working code so it's easier to see what you're doing